# Hibernate bit array to entity mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, usertype

I am trying to map a normalized Java model to a legacy database schema using Hibernate 3.5. One particular table encodes a foreign keys in a one-to-many relationship as a bit array column.

Consider tables `person` and `club` that describes people's affiliations to clubs:

```
person: .----.------.    club: .----.---------.---------------------------.
        | id | name |          | id |   name  | members | binary(members) |
        |----+------|          |----+---------|---------+-----------------|
        |  1 | Bob  |          | 10 | Cricket |       0 |             000 |
        |  2 | Joe  |          | 11 | Tennis  |       5 |             101 | 
        |  3 | Sue  |          | 12 | Cooking |       7 |             111 |   
        '----'------'          | 13 | Golf    |       3 |             100 |
                               '----'---------'---------'-----------------'
```

So hopefully it is clear that `person.id` is used as the bit index in the bit array `club.members`:

```
.---.---.---.
| S | J | B |
| u | o | o |
| e | e | b |
|---+---+---|
| 1 | 0 | 1 |
'---'---'---'
```

In this example the `members` column tells us that:

- no one is a member of Cricket --- no flags set
- Bob/Sue -> Tennis --- flags at positions 1 and 3 are set
- Bob/Sue/Joe -> Cooking --- flags at positions 1, 2 and 3 are set
- Sue -> Golf --- flag at position 3 is set

Now, for this example a join table could've been used instead which would simplify matters and avoid many potential issues - e.g: the maximum range of `members` placing an upper bound on the number of `people` rows. However, I am stuck with this schema and it seems that there were factors in favour of using a bit array column way back when.

In my Java domain I'd like to model this schema with entities like so:

```
class Person {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    ...
}

class Club {
    private Set<Person> members;
    private int id;
    private String name;
    ...
}
```

I am assuming that I must use a `UserType` implementation but have been unable to find any examples where the items described by the user type are references to entities - not literal field values - or composites thereof. Additionally I am aware that I'll have to consider how the `person` entities are fetched when a `club` instance is loaded.

Can anyone tell me how I can tame this legacy schema with Hibernate?

**Update**

I have recently had to revisit this type of mapping in a legacy database. This time around it became apparent that our equivalent of the `members` table was actually a static set and could be hardcoded as an `Enum`. With this simplification it was fairly straightforward to implement a Hibernate `UserType` that converted between the bit array and a set of enums.

Comment: were you ever able to figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

I've never faced this situation but I *think* that you'll need to implement a custom `UserCollectionType` (see chapter [5.2.3. Custom value types](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-types-custom) in Hibernate Core documentation), the `UserCollectionType` being an *extension point which may be used to support any damn collection and collection semantics you like*.

I'm not sure how well they are supported by annotations though (according to [HHH-4417](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-4417), you may have to use a hack). Using `hbm.xml` for this would be a good idea here IMO.

Some more pointers/discussions:

- https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=938522&start=0
- http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/m91832311.html (different case but may give you an idea of how to start)

Comment: Unfortunately it appears that `UserCollectionType` is not that useful in this instance. It's purpose is to allow Hibernate to populate a `Collection` of your choosing with a bunch of entities that it has loaded from a join for example. My case is quite different - I need to have Hibernate interpret the values in a field as a set of keys to entities and then create proxies for these entities, and then add these proxies to a `Collection`. In any case - thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: Have you thought about converting the data in the database in to a temp table and then creating a mapping from that simplified aggregate? You may only be able to read though...just a thought.